# Constants in classes created with Class.new

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'm writing a little piece of code in Ruby (1.9.3), and I use a pair of simple "enum-like" classes, that define some constants with **const_set** and some behavior of these constants (e.g. the class **Days** may have the constants **MON**, **TUE**... and **Days::MON.succ** should evaluate to **TUE**).

I'm really comfortable with these classes. However, while growing my code, i sometimes need to add more of them, and I don't like the idea of having five or more classes that share 99% of source code, e.g.:

```
class Days
  NAMES = %w( MON TUE ... )
  INSTANCES = []

  def initialize(num)
    @num = num
  end

  # An example operation
  def +(n)
    INSTANCES[(@num + n) % INSTANCES.length]
  end

  # Another example operation
  def succ
    self + 1
  end

  def to_s
    NAMES[@num]
  end

  NAMES.each_with_index do |name, idx|
    instance = new(idx)
    INSTANCES[idx] = instance
    const_set name, instance
  end
end

class Months
  NAMES = %w( JAN FEB ... )
  ...
end
```

I was wondering if Ruby's metaprogramming capabilities could be used to generate these classes. However, I'm having an hard time creating **NAMES**, **INSTANCES** and the "enum-named" constants (e.g. **MON**, **TUE**, ...).
Being **const_set** a class method of **Class**, in this code it's context (the value of **self**) is respectively **Days** and **Months**.

When creating a factory method, I'm compelled to do something like this:

```
def enum_new(names_array)
  Class.new do
    const_set "NAMES" []
    names_array.each_with_index do |name, idx|
      NAMES[idx] = name
    end
     ...
  end
end
Days = enum_new(%w| MON TUE ... |)
Months = enum_new(%w| JAN FEB ... |)
```

but this won't work (at least, not like i hoped it to), because **const_set** won't be called in the context of the class whose name is *magically* set (i.e. **Days** and **Months**), but apparently in the context of **Class**; therefore, not only it won't be accessible from the instance methods, but it will be overwrited every time **enum_new** is called with a new array of names as argument. A similar problem shows up when using class variables, because they'll be shared between any class generated with the method (because they'll become class variables of **Class**, i guess).

Is there any way to create constants in a class generated with **Class.new**, obtaining this way classes identical in everything to the original **Days** and **Months** classes, without having to pollute my code with almost identical classes?

Thanks for your attention and patience! :)

Comment: Can you please fill in the code you emit with your elipsis?

Comment: I completed the code of the first class and also added two example operations to show how I need to access the constants in instance methods. Of course instances are accessed via the constants created with const_set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Do your initialization in a `class_exec` block, into which you can pass your name data and where `self` refers to the right class:

```
theClass=Class.new
theClass.class_exec(names) do |names|
  #initialize constants here...
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this actually brought me to some working code that does exactly what I want. However, I noticed that if I `const_set 'NAME', value`in the block associated to **class_exec**, I have to refer to **NAME** as `self::NAME`in the same block, and as `self.class::NAME`in the block associated to **Class.new**. Is there a particular reason why it only works explicitly referencing **self**? Why do constant names in blocks associated to **class_exec**  refer to global constants?

Comment: They don't. `class_exec` can be thought of as the place between the `class` and the `end` of a normal class definition. As for the fact that you must use `self`, that is because until you assign it to a constant, the class is effectively unnamed, and must be accessed from the `self` object or the *variable* `theClass`. Once you assign it to a constant (eg. `Days`), you can access things with `Days::MON`.

Comment: What i meant is that the code `NAMES = ['nothing']; class A; NAMES = ['foo']; end; A.class_exec { NAMES[0] = 'bar' }; p NAMES[0]` prints _bar_. We're using `class_exec`on a named class, but the constant name used in the associated block refers to the global constant `NAMES`, not the one in the `A` class; this is the behavior I wasn't expecting :)

Comment: I think that Ruby has a lot of oddities regarding constants and the `____exec` family of methods. I just found in my Ruby book that in Ruby 1.9, using the `exec` functions, constants are looked up in the scope that `__exec` was called in, meaning that when you called `A.class_exec {NAMES[0]='bar'}`, Ruby is using the constant in the scope that you called `exec` in, that is the global one.

Comment: Thanks, this is great and actually covers my doubts. What's the book you're using? I searched through _The Ruby Programming Language (Flanagan)_ and didn't find a complete coverage of `class_exec` et similia (at least, not complete to the point of addressing this issue).

Comment: Programming Ruby 1.9: The pragmatic Programmer's Guide. This is the best Ruby boot *ever*! Printed documentation for every standard library and core class and module, chapters on everything that the language, and the only thing not there is Rails, but for that, I'd use a Rails book. You should check it out. It's by Dave Thomas, Chad Fowler, and Andy Hunt.